# Get Facebook Oauth Token from behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, oauth, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently writing a web application, which should access user facebook data.

The problem is, that many users access via proxy (all facebook urls are blocked) and therefore it's not possible to use the default oauth mechanism provided by facebook. Any ideas?

Best Regards
Markus

Comment: Any ideas to realize authentification in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

The user must be able to access facebook's servers to authenticate your app.